# Where is the viewport "connected to" the scrollbar in JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I may need to create my own `JScrollPane` subclass. I've looked at the `JScrollPane` and `ScrollPaneLayout` source and believe I understand how it works. However, I can't see where the scrollbar(s) (when present) are "connected to" the viewport. In other words, I was expecting to see the viewport listening to the scrollbar to determine the displayed view coordinates, but find nothing about that. Will someone explain and/or point to me to the code that is doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last thing I thought to examine were the listeners on the `JScrollPane`. Doing so led me to `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI.Handler`, which is where all the "wiring" happens. So that's the answer to the original question - but it points out an unfortunate reality: if I attempt to subclass `JScrollPane` to work as I intend, it seems unlikely that I'll be able to do so without breaking PLaF (with my current understanding of PLaF).

Edit: I found this link to be helpful in understanding `swing.plaf.*`, although it's quite old: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html